# Change QGIS project option "Save paths" to absolute with Python

Tags: file-path

We have many existent project saved with "save paths" option to relative. Therefore, sometimes projects had difficulties to find network folder with this parameter and QGIS become very slow. An easy way to resolve that is to change "save paths" option to absolute but there is no option to set it by default. Can we change it by Python macro or script before saving project to auto convert all project after the next save?

[image]